# Application Ignoring Boolean?

Tags: android, boolean

I am currently trying to create a simple so that when a boolean is set to false, the applications' GoogleAPIClient would not connect.

However, the application, for some reason, goes through and connects anyway even after the boolean has set to false. How do I fix this kind of error?

The code snippet regarding this error is below:

```
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    //Build resources if null
    if (mLocationClient == null) {
        buildLocationClient();
    }
    if (settings == null) {
        settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    }

    Boolean RequestingLU = settings.getBoolean("RequestingLU", true);
    if (RequestingLU) {
        mLocationClient.connect();
        Toast.makeText(this, "You have connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else {
        mLocationClient.disconnect();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Don't connect please", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        StoppedMessage();
    }

}
```

This is the buildLocationClient():

```
protected void buildLocationClient () {
    mLocationClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
}
```

This is an AlertDialog from another activity editing the Setting

```
            AlertDialog.Builder StopDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainMenu.this);
            StopDialog.setTitle(R.string.Stop_Title);
            StopDialog.setMessage(R.string.Stop_Message);
            StopDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.Stop_Button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    editor.putBoolean("RequestingLU", false);
                    editor.apply();
                    Toast.makeText(MainMenu.this, "You have stopped the app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
```

**Some observations**

If RequestingLU is set to false, the "Don't Connect" toast comes up first, then "You have connected" comes up next.

If RequestingLU is set to true, the "Don't Connect" toast does not show up.

Swapping RequestingLU out for !RequestingLU does not work, still does the same effect.

I've tested the RequestLU setting, and it does return false if I change it so. The problem seems to be coming from the application not checking the boolean properly.

When the application is first started, the AlertDialog that is supposed to trigger when RequestingLU is false occurs, despite the default parameter stating that it is true by default.

Changing the default from true to false does no effect at all.

Comment: 1) show `buildLocationClient()` 2) where do you store the prefs?

Comment: 1) I'm not sure if it is relevant, but I will put it in, 2) I just use SharedPreferences to store my Preferences.

Comment: Well of course, but where? I don't see it in your code. For all we know it is always true

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. I do edit the Boolean from another Activity in an AlertDialog, and know that it does change the Preferences to false when I call it to, I'll just put it in if you want to see.

Comment: Why do you call `.disconnect()` in the else? You're not connected, so makes no sense. You just want to 'not connect' if you know what I mean

Comment: Yeah, I just don't want to connect in the first place. Though even without that thing, the application still ignores the check. I've just tried it.

Comment: editor.apply() is asynchronous call and it may take couple of milliseconds before actual changes are committed. In case your second code is getting read quickly then it may give old result. if your read and write are in different thread and execution window is smaller then use editor.commit() instead of apply. See if it works.

Comment: It still connects ;/. Also, I have another problem with it. The default param is supposed to be true, but the AlertDialog tied with RequestingLU to be false occurs when I first start the application, making me go back and set it to be true on the AlertDialog.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
Boolean RequestingLU = settings.getBoolean("RequestingLU", true);
```

to

```
Boolean RequestingLU = settings.getBoolean("RequestingLU", false);
```

The `getBoolean()`function returns the 2nd parameter or the default value passed (in this case "true") if no value has been defined against the key (i.e. "RequestingLU")

Comment: OP says he does change RequestingLU to false, so this won't help

Comment: He changed the value of "RequestingLU" to false but not the default parameter. There might be a chance that Android cannot access the "PREFS_NAME" prefs.